# SQLAlchemy upgrade hangs on azure

Tags: postgresql, azure, sqlalchemy, azure-sql-database, flask-sqlalchemy

When attempting to make upgrades to a postgresql db on azure, the upload hangs for at least an hour with no error messages. `flask db migrate` ran fine with no errors or warnings

I've found a few references to locks being responsible, but what I've been able to find seems to indicate that that's not the problem here.

When I reset the database, the following locks are in place based on `SELECT * FROM pg_locks;`:

```
  locktype  | database | relation | page | tuple | virtualxid | transactionid | classid | objid | objsubid | virtualtransaction | pid |      mode       | granted | fastpath 
------------+----------+----------+------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------+-----+-----------------+---------+----------
 relation   |    14335 |    11577 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 7/21               | 148 | AccessShareLock | t       | t
 virtualxid |          |          |      |       | 7/21       |               |         |       |          | 7/21               | 148 | ExclusiveLock   | t       | t
(2 rows)
```

which I understand refers to the active pgsql connection that I make the query in.

However, after running `flask db upgrade`

the locks change to:

```
   locktype    | database | relation | page | tuple | virtualxid | transactionid | classid | objid | 
objsubid | virtualtransaction | pid |         mode          | granted | fastpath 
---------------+----------+----------+------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+-
---------+--------------------+-----+-----------------------+---------+----------
 relation      |    14335 |    11577 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 11/21              | 588 | AccessShareLock       | t       | t
 virtualxid    |          |          |      |       | 11/21      |               |         |       |          | 11/21              | 588 | ExclusiveLock         | t       | t
 relation      |    14335 |    18183 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 9/4                | 140 | AccessShareLock       | t       | t
 relation      |    14335 |    18180 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 9/4                | 140 | AccessShareLock       | t       | t
 relation      |    14335 |     2685 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 9/4                | 140 | AccessShareLock       | t       | t
 relation      |    14335 |     2684 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 9/4                | 140 | AccessShareLock       | t       | t
 relation      |    14335 |     3455 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 9/4                | 140 | AccessShareLock       | t       | t
 relation      |    14335 |     2663 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 9/4                | 140 | AccessShareLock       | t       | t
 relation      |    14335 |     2662 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 9/4                | 140 | AccessShareLock       | t       | t
 relation      |    14335 |     2615 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 9/4                | 140 | AccessShareLock       | t       | t
 relation      |    14335 |     1259 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 9/4                | 140 | AccessShareLock       | t       | t
 virtualxid    |          |          |      |       | 9/4        |               |         |       |          | 9/4                | 140 | ExclusiveLock         | t       | t
 virtualxid    |          |          |      |       | 8/187      |               |         |       |          | 8/187              | 524 | ExclusiveLock         | t       | t
 relation      |    14335 |    18210 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 7/11               | 132 | AccessShareLock       | t       | t
 relation      |    14335 |    18209 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 7/11               | 132 | AccessShareLock       | t       | t
 relation      |    14335 |    18207 |      |       |            |               
...
 relation      |    14335 |    24607 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 9/4                | 140 | ShareRowExclusiveLock | t       | f
 relation      |    14335 |    24607 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 9/4                | 140 | AccessExclusiveLock   | t       | f
(58 rows)
```

The flask db upgrade command outputs

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade db53564bee93 -> 49f15097679f, empty message
```

and then just hangs.

I don't know why it's hanging and why there aren't any error messages anywhere indicating why it's taking so long to apply the db migrations. I was able to apply migrations previously to this same database, but now it just hangs.

Comment: Hi Matt, is this still an issue? If so, is this the Azure Database for PostgreSQL instance or is this PostgreSQL on an Azure VM?

Comment: Hi Mike, I wasn't able to find a solution in a day or two so I just deleted the db and created a new one and everything worked fine thereafter. It was an azure db for postgres. I haven't had any issues since then.